# How to enqueue assets only on queried pages, excluding the page being queried?

Tags: php, query

How can I enqueue scripts and styles ONLY on admin pages that have a query attached to them?

I have the code below which works, but it also enqueues on the native page of the query. I want to exclude that page because other admin pages use that same page, which eventually leaves unneeded scripts and styles enqueued on the page having a query.

Example and details...

```
if ( isset($_GET['page']) ) {

    global $pagenow;        
    if( in_array( $pagenow, array('admin.php') ) == ( 

    $_GET['page'] == 'QueryExample1' 
        || $_GET['page'] == 'QueryExample2'
}
```

I want to ONLY enqueue on the query pages and not the admin.php page.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This code is correct above is the solution I was looking for.

I just overlooked applying it to some scripts and so I thought it wasn't working.